# Value of $m$ for which cubic equations have common factor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the value of $m$ if equations $x^3 - (m+2)x^2 + 7x - 4m - 1=0$ and  $x^3-(m+3)x^2+11x-4m-4=0$ have a common factor?

Could someone given me hint as how to initiate this question?

Answer (score 4):

Using the usual Euclidean algorithm, the common factor will divide the difference of the polynomials.